# How to avoid a customer group from tax calculation in Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, tax, tax-class

For this task i did below steps to achieve this task.Is it the right way to do this.

**1.** Created a customer group for non Tax : **Tax Free Group**.

**2.** Add a tax class from Sales -> Tax -> Customer Tax Classes : **Tax Free**

**3.** Add a new tax rate :Sales ->Tax -> Manage Tax Zones & Rates. Add a new tax rate, call it “**Tax Free**”, select your country, select “*” for state and zip, and give it a rate of 0. Save the new tax rate.

Finally assigned the tax class **Tax Free** to group **Tax Free Group**.

But in the check out or cart there aren't any tax showing for taxable customers too.
Is my way correct to achieve my requirements?

Answer (score -1):

**Magento 2**

There's a few things you could try:

Go to Stores > Configuration > Sales > Tax and make sure the appropriate categories are set to Enabled and the appropriate Tax Class and Calculation variables are set.

Go to Stores > Configuration > Customers > Create New Account and make sure your default customer group is set up correctly.

Go to Stores > Customer Groups and make sure your normal customer group has the correct Tax Class applied.

Make sure origin shipping address is set correctly under Stores> Configuration > Sales > Shipping Settings>Origin